# Trying to run tests in parallel with golang testify/suite fails

Tags: go, testing, concurrency

I have several tests using `testify/suite` [package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite) and I execute them in parallel as follows

```
type IntegrationSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func TestIntegrationSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, &IntegrationSuite{})
}

func (is *IntegrationSuite) TestSomething() {
    is.T().Log("\tIntegration Testing something")
    for i := range myTestTable {
        i := i
        is.T().Run("Testing "+myTestTable[i].scenarioName, func(_ *testing.T) {
            is.T().Parallel()
...

func (is *IntegrationSuite) TestSomethingElse() {
    is.T().Log("\tIntegration Testing something else")
    for i := range myOtherTestTable {
        i := i
        is.T().Run("Testing "+myOtherTestTable[i].scenarioName, func(_ *testing.T) {
            is.T().Parallel()
...
        })
```

However this panics with

```
panic: testing: t.Parallel called multiple times [recovered]
        panic: testing: t.Parallel called multiple times
```

How can one leverage parallelism with the specific package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `t.Parallel()` on the wrong instance of `testing.T`.

You're spinning up multiple *subtests* using:

```
is.T().Run("Testing "+myOtherTestTable[i].scenarioName, func(_ *testing.T) {...}
```

But instead of marking the *subtest* as parallel, you're marking the *outer parent test* as parallel for every subtest you start:

```
is.T().Parallel() // marks outer test as parallel
```

Instead, bind the subtest func's `testing.T` param to a variable and call `Parallel` on the subtest:

```
        is.T().Run("Testing "+myOtherTestTable[i].scenarioName, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel() // this is the subtest's T instance
            // test code
        })
```

This marks all subtests as parallel within the parent test. If you also want to mark the parent test as parallel with other tests in the package, call `is.T().Parallel()` ***once*** at the beginning of `TestSomethingElse` (not within the subtest)

For more details on parallelism of subtests, see: [Control of Parallelism](https://go.dev/blog/subtests#control-of-parallelism)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the testify suite is currently not "thread safe" and therefore does not support concurrency. There are cases in which tests pass successfully even though they should fail.

Please find the current status as well the reported issues here: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/187